# Windows Azure Websites GitHub Deployment Failing

Tags: git, azure, deployment

Recently my github deployments started failing on a couple of my websites. Everything worked normally and then all started failing with this error and log:

```
Running deployment command...

Command: deploy.cmd
Handling .NET Web Application deployment.
'D:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
operable program or batch file.
```

There is no "D:\Program" in my deploy scripts and I have no idea what is going on. I tried disconnecting and recconecting to the github repository and the problem persists.

Any ideas are welocme. Thanks!

### Update

This is my `deploy.cmd`

```
@echo off
IF "%deployApp%" == "app" (
  deploy.app.cmd
) ELSE (
  IF "%deployApp%" == "admin" (
    deploy.admin.cmd
  ) ELSE (
    echo You have to set deployApp setting to either "app" or "admin"
    exit /b 1
  )
  )
```

And this is `deploy.app.cmd`

```
@echo off

:: ----------------------
:: KUDU Deployment Script
:: ----------------------

:: Prerequisites
:: -------------

:: Verify node.js installed
where node 2>nul >nul
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
  echo Missing node.js executable, please install node.js, if already installed make sure it can be reached from current environment.
  goto error
)

:: Setup
:: -----

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

SET ARTIFACTS=%~dp0%artifacts

IF NOT DEFINED DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE (
  SET DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE=%~dp0%.
)

IF NOT DEFINED DEPLOYMENT_TARGET (
  SET DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=%ARTIFACTS%\wwwroot
)

IF NOT DEFINED NEXT_MANIFEST_PATH (
  SET NEXT_MANIFEST_PATH=%ARTIFACTS%\manifest

  IF NOT DEFINED PREVIOUS_MANIFEST_PATH (
    SET PREVIOUS_MANIFEST_PATH=%ARTIFACTS%\manifest
  )
)

IF NOT DEFINED KUDU_SYNC_CMD (
  :: Install kudu sync
  echo Installing Kudu Sync
  call npm install kudusync -g --silent
  IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error

  :: Locally just running "kuduSync" would also work
  SET KUDU_SYNC_CMD=node "%appdata%\npm\node_modules\kuduSync\bin\kuduSync"
)
IF NOT DEFINED DEPLOYMENT_TEMP (
  SET DEPLOYMENT_TEMP=%temp%\___deployTemp%random%
  SET CLEAN_LOCAL_DEPLOYMENT_TEMP=true
)

IF DEFINED CLEAN_LOCAL_DEPLOYMENT_TEMP (
  IF EXIST "%DEPLOYMENT_TEMP%" rd /s /q "%DEPLOYMENT_TEMP%"
  mkdir "%DEPLOYMENT_TEMP%"
)

IF NOT DEFINED MSBUILD_PATH (
  SET MSBUILD_PATH=%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe
)

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: Deployment
:: ----------

echo Handling .NET Web Application deployment.

:: 1. Build to the temporary path
%MSBUILD_PATH% "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\Property.Web\Property.Web.csproj" /nologo /verbosity:m /t:Build /t:pipelinePreDeployCopyAllFilesToOneFolder /p:_PackageTempDir="%DEPLOYMENT_TEMP%";AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=false;Configuration=Release /p:SolutionDir="%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\.\\" %SCM_BUILD_ARGS%
IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error

:: 2. KuduSync
call %KUDU_SYNC_CMD% -v 50 -f "%DEPLOYMENT_TEMP%" -t "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%" -n "%NEXT_MANIFEST_PATH%" -p "%PREVIOUS_MANIFEST_PATH%" -i ".git;.hg;.deployment;deploy.cmd"
IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

goto end

:error
echo An error has occurred during web site deployment.
call :exitSetErrorLevel
call :exitFromFunction 2>nul

:exitSetErrorLevel
exit /b 1

:exitFromFunction
()

:end
echo Finished successfully.
```

Comment: Can you provide more details?  Maybe a link to the repo or something that would assist in solving the issue?

Comment: I posted the azure log and the  GitHub repo is private. If you're willing to take a look I can give you personally access to my GitHub repository or windows azure websites. I have no idea what other kind of info to provide.

Comment: @DavidCrook I updated the description with the `deploy.cmd` and `deploy.app.cmd`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like after the recent upgrade of the Azure servers(to the new Basic/Standard tier) the technique of choosing which project from the repository is published is not achieved via `deploy.cmd` file but e Configuration setting named `Project` in the project's settings.

I **removed `deploy.cmd` and `.deployment`** files and **added `Project`** variable and the deployment started working again.